# javascript click event, keypress event and doc ready - make functions more efficient

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    iframeSize()
});

$("html").live("click", function( event ){
    iframeSize()
});
$("html").live("keypress", function( event ){
    iframeSize();
});

// resize dialog and iframe when contents change document height
function iframeSize(){
    var iframeHeight = $(document).height();
    window.parent.$('#loginLayer').attr('height', iframeHeight);
    window.parent.$('#loginDialog').css('height', iframeHeight);
}
```

can this code be written more efficiently?

Thanks!

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @j08691 - sweet - didn't know that existed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can remove the 'live' and just do

```
$("body").click( function() { });
```

only really need 'live' to tell jquery to **recheck** the DOM for a new element

( if a new element has been added to the page say with .append(), for example )

outside of this you might be able to achieve your iframe consistant dimensions by using a fluid layout in the parent via css /  setting percentage heights and widths ( ? )

Comment: binding the click function or calling a function inside the click will also mean you can control it ( if you need to disable it etc ) . return false;

Comment: I am using .live, as I have a jQuery dialog that contains the iframe - and I'm using inline form validations that are appended to the iframe DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the iFrameSize function as name directly? Instead of wrapping it inside another function.